# Resharper concatenates strings when I do not want it to

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resharper

I am editing this code with Resharper enabled.

```
var result = DialogService.Confirm("Save Changes?", message,
    "Save" + "Discard");
```

The second line is supposed to be two arguments.  I want it to say this

```
"Save", "Discard");
```

So I put the cursor right after the `+` character and hit backspace.  And instead of just removing the `+`, Resharper goes ahead and concatenates the two strings into one argument.

```
var result = DialogService.Confirm("Save Changes?", message,
    "SaveDiscard");
```

This is not at all what I want.  I just want the backspace to remove the `+` symbol.

Does anyone have any idea what setting would cause this to happen?    I tried turning off all the settings on Editor Behavior but none of them affected it.

I am certain it is Resharper because when I disable it, this not longer occurs.

Comment: Put your cursor right after the closing quote in `"Save"`, type the comma, then delete the space and the `+`. ReSharper  figures if you have an expression like `"Save" + "Discard"` and you delete the `+`, you probably want to simplify the concatenation. It does a few more _helpful_ things like that which are great when it guesses correctly, and perplexing when it doesn't

Comment: I appreciate the suggestion.  I actually did something like that.  But I am not looking to *work around* this behavior.  I want to find out how to turn it off.  Is there a way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

R# will improve this behavior in the next release:

1. Undo after the strings get concatenated will provide an extra step with the `+` character removed.
2. A new option will allow disabling this typing assist altogether.

[image]

Please report issues with R# directly to the development team with "ReSharper | Help | Report a bug or submit feedback".

Comment: Thank you.  The reason I did not report this to Resharper is because I did not think it was a bug I figured it was just some setting buried somewhere that I could not find.  I appreciate the update